# kubectl YAML documentation for a resource

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, kubectl

Is there a `kubectl` command that gives advice about essential fields required in the YAML, or YAML examples, for a given resource?

Currently, when I want a YAML example of a resource, [for example a deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#creating-a-deployment), I search the online documentation. I'd rather stay in the terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`kubectl explain deployment` works for resources which publish openapi specs.

Comment: Thanks for this. Now using `kubectl explain deployment.spec --recursive=true`.